# How to open external links with phonegap in a new layer?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, cordova, webview

I am creating an iphone/android app with Phonegap.

When a user clicks an external link the phone opens the default browser and opens the link in there.

In some apps though I've seen that one can open a layer which slides up (from bottom to top) inside the app and displays the website where the link refers to in this layer (see screenshot). At the bottom, the two buttons say "close" and "open in safari".

**Is there a way to do the same with Phonegap?**

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ChildBrowser`](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/ChildBrowser) plugin does exactly what you want.